# Ensuring only a single instance of the RxBleClient

Tags: rxandroidble

Maybe I'm not understanding the situation correctly, but we're told it's important to have only one instance of the RxBleClient.

Couldn't this be easily accomplished by making it a static member of the Application class?

```
class MyApp extends Application {
    static RxBleClient rxBleClient; 
    ...
}
```

Also, I'm having a hard time understanding this code (from your Application class):

```
   public static RxBleClient getRxBleClient(Context context) {
       RxBleApp application = (RxBleApp) context.getApplicationContext();
       return application.rxBleClient;
   }
```

Could you help me understand what it's doing, and why? Why couldn't it simply

```
return rxBleClient;
```

Answer (score 0):

It can be accomplished with taking the static member of the class. Tough it is more elegant to pass it through the instance of `RxBleApp` which make it more testable (if there were any tests for the sample part).

The `RxBleClient` is referenced in the `RxBleApp` which is the android `Application`. The application context can be retrieved from the `Context`.

Comment: I am refactoring and planning to put the BLE code into a Bound Service. Is this reasonable? The idea: in my new BluetoothService class, put this: `static RxBleClient mBleClient;`. And in its onCreate(), put `mBleClient = RxBleClient.create(this);`. Then add a method `public static RxBleClient getRxBleClient() { return mBleClient; }`. If I understand, when I bind a Service I am given a reference to an _instance_ of it, but it is OK to call its static methods with this reference. I still don't fully understand why you create and then discard a new instance of the Application. Could you explain?